# open the file upload dialogue box onclick the image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open the image upload file dialogue box if I click the button tag. Is it possible? If so how can I do it in PHP?

```
while{
    echo "<td><button><img src='".$cfet['productimage']."' width='50' height='40'></button></td>";
}
```

Comment: PHP runs on the sever. It can **NOT** "pop up" anything on the client.

Comment: @MarcB - But there's a JavaScript tag in the question... JavaScript lets you programmatically open a file modal, Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3wRpA/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Include input `type="file"` element on your HTML page and on the click event of your button trigger the click event of input type file element using trigger function of jQuery

The code will look like:

```html
<input type="file" id="imgupload" style="display:none"/> 
<button id="OpenImgUpload">Image Upload</button>
```

And on the button's click event write the **jQuery** code like :

```js
$('#OpenImgUpload').click(function(){ $('#imgupload').trigger('click'); });
```

This will open File Upload Dialog box on your button click event..

Comment: How to call trigger in angular 2+

Comment: When I tried this wasn't working... the click should be in document.ready ( or )

 $(function () {
        $('#openImgUpload').click(function () { $('#imgUpload').trigger('click');   });
    });

Answer (score 23):

```
<input type="file" id="imgupload" style="display:none"/>
<label for='imgupload'> <button id="OpenImgUpload">Image Upload</button></label>
```

On click of **for=** attribute will automatically focus on "file input" and upload dialog box will open

Comment: Worked for me in my React app.

Comment: Nice clean solution without JS

Comment: whoha...simple that I thought

Answer (score 14):

you need to add a little hack to achieve this.

You can hide a file upload(`input type=file`) behind your `button`.

and onclick of your button you can trigger your file upload click.

It will open a file upload window on click of button

```
<button id="btnfile"> 
 <img src='".$cfet['productimage']."' width='50' height='40'>
</button> 
<div class="wrapper"> //set wrapper `display:hidden`
     <input type="file" id="uploadfile" /> 
</div>
```

and some javascript

```
$("#btnfile").click(function () {
    $("#uploadfile").click();
});
```

here is a fiddle for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/QmyHV/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 7):

Also, You can write all inline, direct at html code:

```
<input type="file" id="imgupload">
<a href="#" onclick="$('#imgupload').trigger('click'); return false;">Upload file</a>
```

> return false; - will be useful to decline anchor action after link was clicked.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" id="pic1" style="display:none;"/>
<label for="pic1">
    <img src="dist/img/picfilename.png">
</label>
```

Above code is tested and it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
  <label for="profileImage"> 
  <a style="cursor: pointer;"><em class="fa fa-upload"></em> Change Profile 
  Image</a></label> 
  <input type="file" name="profileImage" id="profileImage" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: This can be achieved without jquery.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

you can show the file selection dialog with a onclick function, and if a file is choosen (onchange event) then send the form to upload the file

```
 <form id='foto' method='post' action='upload' method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden"> 
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" onchange="this.form.submit()"/> 
  </div>

  <i class='fa fa-camera' onclick="fileInput.click();"></i>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="OpenImgUpload" onclick="$('#imgupload').trigger('click');">Image Upload</button>
<input type="file" id="imgupload" style="display:none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
 <form method="post" action="#" id="#">
<div class="form-group files color">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" multiple="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.files input {
outline: 2px dashed #92b0b3;
outline-offset: -10px;
-webkit-transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear;
transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear;
padding: 120px 0px 85px 35%;
text-align: center !important;
margin: 0;
width: 100% !important;
height: 400px;
```

}

```
.files input:focus{    
    outline: 2px dashed #92b0b3; 
    outline-offset: -10px;
   -webkit-transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear;
    transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear;
  border:1px solid #92b0b3;
```

}

```
.files{ position:relative}
   .files:after {  pointer-events: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 60px;
     left: 0;
    width: 50px;
   right: 0;
   height: 400px;
  content: "";
  background-image: url('../../images/');
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

```
.color input{ background-color:#f1f1f1;}
.files:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #2ea591;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- File input (hidden) -->
<input type="file" id="file1" style="display:none"/>    

<!-- Trigger button -->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="openSelect('#file1')">

<script type="text/javascript">                            
function openSelect(file)
{
  $(file).trigger('click');
}
</script>
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!--Hide input field to open it using button-->
        <input type="file" #file11 style="display:none">
        
        and <button type="file" (click)="file11.click()">Open file dialog</button>
```